# How to perform wildcard search in neo4j?

Tags: search, wildcard, neo4j

Is it possible to search, say, for all customers whose name starts with "A", in neo4j graph database? The neo4j wiki has a link for this subject but it's broken, 
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Design_Guide#Searching_by_wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the following pages:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/indexing.html
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/auto-indexing.html

good luck!